# Why cancer disease is named after sun signs ?

Tags: terminology

I googled it, It didn't helped me a lot.

So Why cancer disease is named after sun signs ?

Comment: duplicate of http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/26086/3340

Answer (score 2):

It isn't. The name of the [constellation/zodiac sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancer_(constellation)) and of the malignant cell diseases comes from the Latin word ["cancer"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cancer#English), which means "crab".

This name for the disease dates back to the Greeks and Hippocrates, who used the word "karkinos" (the Greek equivalent) because the veins around the tumors they observed made the disease look like a crab [3](https://web.archive.org/web/20110716111312/http://www.cancerdecisions.com/speeches/galen1989.html).

Answer (score 2):

The word "cancer" comes from the Latin *cancer*, meaning "crab". Both the Latin *cancer* and the Greek *karkinos* (hence "carcinoma"), that also means crab, come from the proto-Indo-European "qark", meaning "to be hard (like a crab)".

Historically, tumours have been called this way because the similarity of some tumours with a crab. According to "Etymology Online":

> Greek physicians Hippocrates and Galen, among others, noted similarity of crabs to some tumors with swollen veins.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you post any photos of tumors that look like crabs?

Comment: Personally, despite having seen countless carcinomas (I'm not a physician, but a biology teacher), I've *never* seen one that, for me, looks like a crab.

Comment: The ancients just had such a vivid imagination! Or maybe crabs looked different back then. :)

Comment: From personal experience... I had two poor bunnies with mammal tumours. They grow in a roughly crab-shaped way, you can feel them being encapsulated in this shape under their skin. You can even move them back and forth a little. If the old greeks got their first idea of tumours from those being palpable and close to skin, this might be a reason to compare it to "a crab under the skin".